# Prevent Google Maps InfoWindow to set focus on first element (i.e. a button)

Tags: jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

Whenever I load a Google Maps InfoWindow that contains a clickable HTML element (i.e. a bootstrap button) the first clickable element has the focus rendering the UX less immediately readable.

API: I'm calling [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key]](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=%5Bkey%5D) and getting maps-api-v3 (3.45.8)

[image]

How do I not have any visible element have the focus?

Comment: What Maps JavaScript API version are you on? There seems to be a recent issue focusing the first element in the Info Window which might be related to what you are having: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190075886

Comment: @jabamataro I'm calling https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[key] and getting maps-api-v3 (3.45.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add tabindex="0" to any non-visible HTML element, I can prevent the button from getting the focus and the UI is more readable.